# VBA code dragging down a formula in a column next to a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel, autofill

I'm getting an '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error after I was trying to automatically "drag down" a formula in column E after updating the pivot table in range A:D. The length of the pivot table can be different (sometimes longer, sometimes shorter) after updating, that's why I need to have the column E dynamic.

The code I used:

```
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("E5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5;Table1[[ID_Number]:[Notes]];37;1)"
Range("E5").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E5:E" & LastRow)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your line

```
Range("E5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5;Table1[[ID_Number]:[Notes]];37;1)"
```

needs to be

```
Range("E5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A5,Table1[[ID_Number]:[Notes]],37,1)"
```

Formulas (unless using the `FormulaLocal` property) need to be written in English.